# Goodness of fit test for partial proportional odds model in R?

Tags: r, model, ordinal-data, goodness-of-fit

I have fit two partial proportional odds models in R using the `clm()` function from the ordinal package, with nominal effects (more on the function and package [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/ordinal/f/inst/doc/clm_article.pdf)). I have an ordinal response variable and several independent variables of different classes. I was wondering what would be a good way to assess goodness of fit for my models and compare them to each other in R.

Example of the model:

```r
model2 <- ordinal::clm(VH ~ Interp.trust + Pol.part + Civ.norms + 
             edu_lvl + sex + health_status + media + covid_hist + 
             trust_science, 
             nominal = ~ Link.trust + Soc.part + age + risk_perc, 
             data = FINALIT)
```

Answer (score 2):

After some more research, I think I am able to answer my own question. Please if are any corrections comment below/post another answer! I am very new to all this!

So, anova() (analysis of variance) in R can be used for clm models, which I was not sure about ([source](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/ordinal.pdf), "anova.clm" section). This can only be done with nested models, but since what I want to check is whether the addition of certain variables to model 2 (that were not included in model 1) is an improvement, this is perfect for me.

So I run this code:

```
anova(model2, model1) #model 2 first as it is the one with the added variables
```

Which returns this output:

```
Likelihood ratio tests of cumulative link models:
 

       no.par    AIC  logLik LR.stat df Pr(>Chisq)    
model1     52 2850.5 -1373.2                          
model2     63 2776.7 -1325.3  95.769 11  1.225e-15 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In this case, the null hypothesis is that both models fit the data equally, therefore the addition of the variables in model 2 is not efficient and we should prefer model 1. The alternative hypothesis is that model 2 fits the data significantly better than model 1, so the added variables should be kept. (I found [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6505/likelihood-ratio-test-in-r) on cross validated very useful to interpret the output)

As you can see in my analysis the p value is significantly below the .05 threshold, meaning that I can reject the null hypothesis and conclude that the model with the added variables is preferable to the simpler one.

Comment: *"the null hypothesis is that both models fit the data equally"* More specifically, the null hypothesis is often that the effect of the added variable is zero. You could formulate that as fitting the data equally, but it is a bit confusing or unclear. This is because,  the model with the extra variable will fit differently.

Comment: Also unclear with that formulation is that it is not directly obvious that the null hypothesis expresses a preference for the smaller model. The model with the extra variable requires strong proof in order to be accepted (if a requirement of a small p-value is chosen, which is often the case with hypothesis testing).

Comment: Another nuance is that this comparison of two models is not a goodness of fit test. Goodness of fit is a test for how close the modeled distribution is equal to the true distribution (and that true distribution is estimated with the sample).

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications @SextusEmpiricus! What would actually be a good goodness of fit test in this case?

Comment: You could perform a [G-test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test). But I am not sure how this would work if you only have single observations for a given set of regressor variables  (all $O_i=1$). In that case the G statistic is equal to$$G=-\sum_i\log(\hat{p}_i)$$where the subscript $i$ refers to the $i$-th observation and $\hat{p}_i$ is the predicted value of the observed class. Note: this value $G$ is the same as the likelihood for your fitted model...

Comment: ... What you could do is compute a p-value using simulations but I am not sure how to interpret the result. You are likely gonna have a misfit, because no model is perfect.

Comment: Aside from a Monte Carlo simulation, you can also use a normal distribution approximation. The observed $G$ is a sum of several values that will approximately follow a normal distribution.

Comment: Unfortunately it is quite difficult to get a "general goodness of fit" for a non-Gaussian regression model that is easy to interpret. You can try one of the Psuedo R-squared measures, but they all have their own drawbacks. Comparing your models to each other and to the null model (`clm(y ~ 1)`) is about the best you can do. I would also recommend plotting the observed vs predicted values (since they are ordinal you can use a heatmap or bubble plot or something) which can show you where the model most often gets it wrong